# One of my players is a problem player

Tags: problem-players

I'm an new DM (only 7 sessions under my belt) and one of my friends has been troubling at best.

He has been looking up rules and disrupting the game even after I have told him the rule 20 times. He has also been looking behind my DM-screen to get the rule-book for rules I have already explained to him.

He's also talking back to things that happen, like he got [redacted] cut off and he replied that he had no [redacted] which was just absurd (keep in mind he said this as it happened not while he was creating his character).

What do I do?

Comment: What is the issue with looking up rules? And why did you have the characters "[redacted] get cut off"?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. Can you give more details on your group, like age and experience? A 7 y.o. RPG-beginner and a grizzled former AD&D don't need the same solution for remembering rules. Can you also specify why it's a problem that the player want to access the rule-book?

Comment: He rolled low on a with a shield and I can't remember the monster but I sliced his [redacted] off

Comment: @kviiri he is constantly going behind my screen and checking the rules instead of asking me to give them plus he also does it as I read it to them and sometimes he takes 20 minutes looking at the rule in his phone when I already read it holding everyone up

Answer (score 5):

As the DM, it's your responsibility to keep your game running smoothly. If a player isn't working out, you need to take them aside and suggest that your game isn't a good fit for their play style, and ask them not to come back.

(I had to do this with a player last week. The other players took it well; two of them approached me afterward and thanked me for removing the disruptive player so they could get back to the game.)

As an aside, I think most groups would regard it as super weird and inappropriate to tell a player that a monster had "cut their [redacted] off". This isn't funny and it's not fun for the player. I recommend not having genital mutilation be a part of your role-playing fantasy.

Comment: Thanks its just that these are my friends that I've known for years and they have that kind of humour p

Comment: Plus I'm a teenager, I can't just tell them to not come back 8 see them at school and they live roughly 50 meters away

Comment: @user40638 It's "Please do not come to our RPG because it's not fun for us, but we'll still hang out and play boardgames/watch a movie/...", not "I don't want to see you ever again".

Comment: Yeah but he's also a very sensitive person and one of my best friends

Comment: This might be a better question for https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ (?)

Comment: @user40638 Not exactly your situation, but the quote in the 2nd point of this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80000/when-to-kick-out-frequently-absent-and-disruptive-players/80009#80009) (and its linked context) seems helpful